# Firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.String

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use Firebase Database but I get that exception (in the title). First I wrote under onDataChange:  `Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);`
 but then they asked me to use a generictypeindicator, which I did. However, I now get this new exception. How do I fix this?

Here are some important lines of code
[image]

[image]

```
    //accessing the firebase database
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    //creates a database references
    databaseRef1=database.getReference().child("Ben_Ptolemy");
    databaseRef2=database.getReference().child("Ptolemy_Ben");

 sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();

            if(!messageText.equals("")){
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("message", messageText);
                map.put("user", "Ben");
                databaseRef1.push().setValue(map);
                databaseRef2.push().setValue(map);
                messageArea.setText("");
            }
        }
    });

    databaseRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("firebase received", "true");


            GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>> genericTypeIndicator = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, String>>() {};
            Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(genericTypeIndicator );
            String message = map.get("message").toString();
            String userName = map.get("user").toString();

            if(userName.equals("Ben")){
                addMessageBox("You:-\n" + message, 1);
            }
            else{
                addMessageBox("Ptolemy" + ":-\n" + message, 2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post your Firebase data so that we can figure out your mapping

Comment: which firebase data? the console?

Comment: Your db data where you attach the listener...

Comment: Also do post the location where databaseRef1 is listening to

Comment: database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseRef1=database.getReference().child("Ben_Ptolemy");
databaseRef2=database.getReference().child("Ptolemy_Ben");

Comment: Please post it in the question... Also a screenshot of the data in the console wouldn't hurt. This is a mapping issue... Post this and we'll be able to solve this

Comment: Ok added in the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally got this to work. I used `addChildEventListener` instead of `addValueEventListener` and replaced `Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);` with `Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();` and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

So as i said in comments, this is a mapping issue.

A Map can only be used if the location is a json itself

Eg:

```
"Something":{
    "Name":"john"
}
```

So if this is the Firebase data node, you use a Map as you have used.

ok based on what you've shown you do the following

```
String message = dataSnapshot.child("message").getValue(String.class);
```

This will give you the value of message for your ben or other nodes if you attach listeners in the same way as you've currently done

Comment: No sorry, this is what I wrote myself in the console. But when I actually send a message through the app, the message gets shown like this in the console (please see main post, I updated the picture) Thank you  EDIT: added 2 pictures

Comment: Ok check the updated answer. Should give you correct values

Comment: what did you edit? the answer is the same. Wwait let me try

Comment: No man, the way I'm showing.. the way to get data is different. There's a child method in between. It looks similar ;)

Comment: I tried, but String message gets a null value. Which means it's not reading anything.

Comment: Damn it, my bad... Didn't see that u had used push()... Do not use push() just use setValue, then this answer will work... Push doesn't make sense in your current structure... You'll not be able to access data of you push it like this. You'll have to run a loop on get children and it'll be unnecessarily complicated. Remove push while setting value

Comment: stil null exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168868/discussion-between-kushan-and-david-benalal).

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs generally when you set the database name and class name same! Change anyone of them. It will okay!